# Interpret "Find action" results on Safari

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to create an AppleScript that can find text on a webpage and tell me the amount of matches I received(Command + F).

I already know how to do the "Find" part:

```
  tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.5
    keystroke "f" using {command down}
  end tell
```

However, I do not know how to *interpret* these results, such as tell me whether there is a match, or how many matches I have.

Is there any way to do this?(If it seems a bit vague, I can be more specific)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [@user3439894](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439894/user3439894) and his sentiments about using **UI scripting** (that is—in this case—getting *System Events* to issue mouse clicks and keypresses on your behalf).  Although it has its uses in other areas, it's by far and away my personal least favourite method to achieve a goal, and one of last resort.

Two very quick reasons why it can be a fragile implementation is: **1)** the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> shortcut used to initiate the `Find...` menu command could change, either by your own doing, or if it were to be overridden by a systemwide shortcut that supersedes *Safari's* claim to it (in fact, for this reason, I would personally trigger the `Find...` command via the `menu bar`, which *System Events* can `click` on your behalf.  Menu items tend not to change like shortcuts, unless regional language settings do); and **2)** if *Safari* loses focus during the time the keypresses are issued and the search is initiated, it messes up the whole command flow in your script, and will at best give you no results, but more likely, throw an error in a later part of the script.

I'm going to demonstrate two alternative methods of searching a *Safari* webpage for a piece of text, and obtaining the number of times it matches throughout the whole document.

#### 1. *Safari*'s `do JavaScript` AppleScript command

Most modern web browsers have the ability to run JavaScript code inside their tabs, and *Safari* can too.  AppleScript can take command of this very useful function, provided you give it permission to do so by going into the *Develop* menu of *Safari* and ticking **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** and **Allow Remote Automation** (the latter of which will already be on, I'm guessing).  There's another menu item called **Allow JavaScript from Smart Search Field**—I would advise you keep this one off, otherwise it could potentially allow naughty websites to issue commands to your computer and cause mischief.

```
    use A : application "Safari"


    set D to the front document of A

    set s to "AppleScript" -- the search string

    try
        set n to (do JavaScript ¬
            "document" & ¬
            ".body" & ¬
            ".innerText" & ¬
            ".match(/" & s & "/ig)" & ¬
            ".length;" in D) as integer -- the number of matches
    on error
        set n to 0
    end try
```

To break this down: `s` is the search string that you would otherwise be typing into the search box.  It is fed into a JavaScript command, that has the following components:

- **`document`:** a reference to the *Safari* webpage document;
- **`body`:** the body of the document, as opposed to, say, the header or the footer.  It's the main bulk of the webpage that users see in front of them;
- **`innerText`:** the text contained within the body of the document, free of any HTML formatting, but preserving whitespace;
- **`match()`:** a method or function in JavaScript where the search string `s` is used to perform a search within the `innerText` and return an array listing all of the matches;
- **`length`:** a property of the array returned by `match()` that reports how many elements is contains, and this equates to the number of matches found during the search.

It's all one command, which, written in full on a single line, looks like this (using the search string `"AppleScript"`):

```
    document.body.innerText.match(/AppleScript/ig).length;
```

It returns a number, which is stored in the variable `n`, and that's it.

This is my favourite method that I would elect to use myself, as it's unlikely to break, and it's nice and fast.

I should point out that `match()` actually searches and matches using a [Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info).  I won't go into them right now, but it means that the search string `s` will need to be a little careful if using any special characters:

```
    \   [   ]   {   }   ^   $   .   |   ?   *   +   (   )
```

All you need to be aware of is that, if your search string uses any of these characters, you should precede it with a double-backslash `\\`.  So, for example, if I wanted to search for `"matches I received(Command + F)"` (which uses `(`, `)` and `+`), then I would declare my variable `s` as:

```
    set s to "matches I received\\(Command \\+ F\\)"
```

#### 2. Chop & Measure

This method is useful if you don't wish to enable *Remote JavaScript* in your browser, or simply want something that's straightforward to remember and implement off the top of your head next time.

It's simple text manipulation, using AppleScript's `text item delimiters` and a bit of counting:

```
    use A : application "Safari"


    set D to the front document of A

    set s to "AppleScript" -- the search string

    set T to text of D -- the webpage text content
    set l to {initialValue:length of T, finalValue:missing value}

    set the text item delimiters to s
    set T to text items of T
    set the text item delimiters to ""
    set T to T as text
    set l's finalValue to length of T

    set |l| to (l's initialValue) - (l's finalValue)

    set n to |l| / (length of s)
```

*Safari* has a useful AppleScript property called `text`, which refers to the text content of the specified `document` or `tab` (it also has another property called `source` that contains the HTML source of the `document` or `tab`).

Here's the breakdown:

- The value of *Safari*'s `text` property—which is the text content of the webpage—is stored in a variable, `T`;
- The `length` of `T` is read and stored.  This equates to the number of characters on the whole webpage;
- The `text item delimiters` are set to the search string, `s`, (which does **not** need to worry about special characters, so don't insert unnecessary backslashes in this one).  The `text item delimiters` basically **erase** all occurrences of `s` from within `T`;
- Then the `length` of T is read again.  If `s` found any matches in `T`, it means that the `length` of T—the number of characters—will have reduced;
- It will have reduced by the number of characters in `s` **for each match** that occurred.  Therefore, turning the equation round a bit, the number of matches, `n`, is equal to the change in `length` of `T` divided by the `length` of `s`.

---

There are other ways to search a webpage with AppleScript, JavaScript, bash, etc., but I think these two serve as reasonable **examples** of how to achieve the same goal using very different methods.  I refer to them as examples, because you might need to make small adjustments to the script to cater for your own needs, such as inserting backslashes where necessary in the first example, or considering in the second how you'd handle the situation if you set `s` to be an empty string `""` (it will throw an error, but this is easily managed).

They also both return `real` values for `n`, i.e. `11.0`.  It's easy to see why in the second example, but I assume it's just a type conversion between JavaScript and AppleScript in the first example (I don't know).  Therefore, purely for neatness, I would then coerce the returned value into an integer as I did in the first one, so it reads `11` instead of `11.0`:

```
    set n to (...) as integer
```

but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I must say that **UI Scripting** can be messy and unreliable. I'd suggest you find a different way to accomplish whatever the real goal is.

That said, using **Safari** in **macOS High Sierra 10.13.3** set to this web page, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will set the *variable* `theSearchResult` to the result of the search for the word "vague":

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using command down
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "vague"
    delay 0.2
    set theSearchResult to (value of static text 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Safari")
    delay 0.2
    key code 53 -- # Esc
end tell
return theSearchResult

Result:
"1 match"
```

- Note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.

The search result can be one of the following, `Not found` or an integer followed by the word `match`, e.g. `1 match`, and possibly something else, not sure as I've not done extensive testing.

How you want to interpret the result is up to you. You could use a `if` *statement* on the `theSearchResult`, e.g.:

```
if theSearchResult contains "Not found" then
    -- # Do something.
    -- # Your code goes here.

else
    -- # Do something else.
    -- # Your code goes here

end if
```

Another factor to consider is how is it being searched, i.e. `Starts With` or `Contains`.  I believe the *default* in for **Safari** in **macOS High Sierra 10.13.3**  is `Starts With`.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.